# Nuget Command Line - Packages Being Installed But Not Added As a Reference in the Project

Tags: nuget

I am installing all my packages in a project using the following nuget command line command:

```
nuget install packages.config -o ..\packages
```

Everything is fetched correctly and added to the packages, yet no references are added to the project. If right click the solution folder and select to manage the nuget packages, I can see the packages installed in the project yet there are no references added for the next packages?

Am I missing a step here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is by design. We never modify the project file from outside of VS. The command you're running is basically "restore my packages folder" and should be used with this workflow http://docs.nuget.org/docs/workflows/using-nuget-without-committing-packages.